# Eclipse configuration issue for android

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I am using mac and working on android project.I just updated the ADT and some other plugins from Help>Check for Updates
then I updated the sdk tools and android build tools in SDK manager as well to make them compatible to ADT 23.x.x
But after I restarted the eclipse it stated giving me error.
I downgraded the ADT but there are still errors in almost my all projects that

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

Also it shows an error dialog when i open eclipse.
here is the error log..

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'AndroidPopupWindow'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'AndroidTabLayout'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'ChelseaFit'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'DBPorjectTest'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'Feedback App'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'GoEvent'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'GroceryApp'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'Islamic Lagacy'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'MainActivity'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'MyFirstTestActivity'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'ORMLiteDemo'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'SMSGe'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'SocketIO'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'SpeechToTextDemo'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'TestInAppPurchase'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'Training'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'ViewFlipper'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_10'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_2'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_3'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_4'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_5'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_6'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_7'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_8'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7_9'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'library'.
com/android/utils/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
```

Please suggest me what could be wrong I am just stuck after updating ADT and up till now has spent more than a day on fixing it but getting no success.
Regards:Ali

Answer (score 0):

When changing the version of the ADT you also have to make sure to make the necessary updates through Android SDK Manager. To know which ADT version works with what Android SDK Tools version you should check http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: Followed but still same error.            Download the ADT Plugin Downloaded zip file .
Start Eclipse,Help > Install New Software.
Click Add, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
Select the downloaded ADT-23.0.3.zip file and click OK.
Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
Click Next.
then click Finish.
When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.